# How to run an executable in Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows-terminal

I want to run an executable with [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal). Something like this:

```
wt.exe myConsoleApp.exe
```

But this only opens the Terminal itself.

Making the Terminal the default for all `ps1`, `bat` and command line `exe` files would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: This is now possible with:

```
wt myConsoleApp.exe
```

Comment: It opens new window. How to do it in the same window?

Comment: @AgentFire you should add `-w <window-id>` like `wt -w 1 myConsoleApp.exe`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows 11:

If `wt.exe` does not work, check if Windows Terminal / wt.exe is enabled under "App execution aliases" (in Settings).

[Go to Settings > Apps > Apps & features > App execution aliases. Check that the line containing wt.exe is checked. (click for photo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giZeB.png)

Answer (score -1):

You should include `start` when you want to run an executable. For example:

```
start wt.exe
```

Also note that, you should include the full file path if you are not currently on the directory of your executable file.

Comment: I suspect the OP knows how to start an executable, but wants console applications to be displayed in a Windows Terminal window (instead of the default `conhost` window).