# How do I run my .c program from terminal in one line?

Tags: c, gcc, terminal, mingw, execution

I use the **Min-GW GCC compiler** on **Windows 10**. Every time I compile, I need to make a **.exe** and then run it. Could there be any way to do the whole thing in one step?

Comment: `gcc file.c -o file.exe&&./file`? Alternatively, tcc can run C, too

Comment: Learning Make or just writing a small C program that sends shell commands using `system()` in `stdlib.h` to compile as well as execute !

Comment: This question may not be very on-topic ...

Comment: Get some [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), there are many of them.

Comment: `&&` only works in PS7 and cmd prompt. [Here's how to `&&` in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/564092/6243352) -- or use a script, use make or the other options suggested here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine commands in windows like you do on linux or macos!

```
gcc compilefile && c:/executefile.exe
```

(you need to replace that stuff with min-gw and your exe path)

links:

- [How do I run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd#8055390)
- [How to run an executable in Windows Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722060/how-to-run-an-executable-in-windows-terminal)